# How to build complex dynamic hierarchy view (1-n & n-1)?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, sharepoint

Does anyone know how to create a complex dynamic hierarchy treeview with ASP.NET or Silverlight or any other technology that can be viewed on a SharePoint page?

We have records in our database connected to each other with keywords `predecessor` and `successor`. Now we want to have a visual overview of these records on the screen showing the hierarchy.

Example of what we want to create:
[image: Complex Hiearchy View]

I have found many solutions for custom treeviews, charts, hierarchy views, .. but none of them could create our view dynamically.

EDIT: The boxes should be interactive and the sollution should support most common browser without installing software for the client. (If possible)

EDIT 2: The diagram will show all the courses (=box) for a training. Some courses are grouped in modules (=color) and for some courses, you have to succesfully passed one or more other courses.

Your help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Sadly have to say your need is very particular. Of course, for this kind of presentation the rules for the hierarchy are very important and making your requirement unique (I guess). We could guide you about how to draw stuff in the UI but the logic to make the right position for everything is up to you.

Comment: I've been thinking about making a table or grid. I could fill that grid with buttons based on a algortithm. With some logic this could work, but i don't have a clue for making the lines or arrows. How would you draw this in UI? I forgot to mention that they must be clickable and some of them must be disabled if some tests fails for that record.

Comment: i've edited my question to be more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the relationships are interconnected these are not actually hierarchies. You want a directed graph with custom user controls for the nodes.

Try these (most are open source or free):

- [Quickgraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/)
- [Graph Sharp (Graph#)](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/)
- [Node XL](http://nodexl.codeplex.com/)
- [Microsoft Automatic Graph Layout](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/f1303e46-965f-401a-87c3-34e1331d32c5/default.aspx)
- [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/)

Comment: Thank you for this useful list. I'll look at all of them in detail to look if i can find one that is useful for me. I've seen already the Sequence chart of FlowChart that might work. But it requires to install clickonce. We don't want our client to install much. But i'll keep it behind :)

Comment: @Thomas Dekiere: `Click Once` is a technology for simplified installation of WinForms applications, rather than adding an extra step it makes installs easier (downloadable from a web site). The fact that it is needed means FlowChart.net is probably not suitable for Silverlight so I have removed it.